# How To Send Email to Delegated Person in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

[DelegationFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QHYH.png)I have configured EmailWorkItemHandler or Email Service Task in JBPM.
new org.jbpm.process.workitem.email.EmailWorkItemHandler("smtp host",port,"user@doamin.com", "password","true");
 I am using REST API call to perform tasks.
What i want to do is , When i delegate task to another person , say i delegate a task to ABC user then email should go to ABC user.
How do i configure email address to send email to particular user ?
How to send email to delegated person ?
Could anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is writing custom implementation for [Task event listener's](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/main/java/org/jbpm/services/task/events/DefaultTaskEventListener.java#L194) "afterTaskDelegatedEvent" method. Refer to [code](https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-notifications/blob/master/jbpm-notifications-impl/src/main/java/org/jbpm/extensions/notifications/impl/listeners/NotificationTaskEventListener.java) for sample implementation.

Comment: I forget to mention , i am using bpmn  designer to use email service task. So i am not sure where to write this class there ? any idea ? .

Comment: Email service task will only trigger email when the workflow reaches a service task node, it won't trigger an email when the human task is delegate to another user. For that, you will have to write custom task listeners. Refer [blog][1] for creating custom task listeners.


  [1]: https://techblogtoprogram.wordpress.com/2020/02/19/create-custom-task-listeners-for-jbpm-process/

Comment: I have attached my flow here.My flow is like i have set to_email to default email.so first time it send email to default person.once he delegate task to another person , i want to set the to_email to newly delegated person.can i set to_email in request body or param?or i have to write custom code as you suggested above ?

Comment: In your workflow, initial email service task will send an email then flow would go to the human task, now once the human task is completed then it checks for the value of "isDelegated". If it's true then it will go back to email service task and again create a new human task. So if as long as "isDelegated" remain true it will loop and keep creating a new human task. I am not sure if that's your requirement.

Comment: myflow is like,when a new case instace create,it autostart the task and send email to human.now if human delegate task to another human instead claiming a task then isdelegated set to true , at that time email should be sent to person whom task is delegated.so how and where do i set to_email var?

Comment: Can i do like http://localhost/kie-server/services/rest/serer/container/c_id/tasks/tid/states/completed?isDelegate=true but what if human delegate task before completing it?

Comment: In the workflow shared only when the human task is completed then it checks for the value of "isDelegated" and the next node would be triggered not before that. Writing a custom task listener would be the solution to your requirement.